# How can save drop down selected values. dropdown located in table column as shown in the image

Tags: php

I want to save each row by getting the ID of selected value in the dropdown like this:

[image: Like This]

Comment: Have you actually tried anything? If so, what have you tried? What worked, what didn't work? What is the actual problem you're seeing? Or are you expecting someone to understand your requirements and write your code for you? Show us examples of the code you're currently using.

Answer (score 0):

This is supposed to be a comment, but i have a low reputation here
Hi Khan i do not really understand what you mean.
A dropdown is basically a select option. The attribute "value" is what gets posted as the selected value. 
To save the value, simply have this:

```
$selected_value = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['name_of_dropdown_from_html_form']);
```

To get the value on an update form, do this:

```
<select id="id_of_field" name="name_of_field" class="form-control">
    <?php
    #i assume your select dropdown list is from a database. 
    #SO in that table, we have two columns, id_of_table and list_type. 
    #For example a list of different types of cars,
    #id(1) and list_type(BMW).
    #SO now we check if the id of the car is in the current dropdown list
    $list = $class->get_list();

    foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['id_of_table'] == $value['list_type']) {
            $selected = "selected='selected'";
            echo "<option value=\"{$value['id_of_table']}\" {$selected}>{$value['list_type']}</option>";
        } else {
            echo "<option value=\"{$value['id_of_table']}\">{$value['list_type']}</option>";
        }
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

try and integrate this with your project and let me know what you get